# Double clicking a row and column in ALV Grids

Tags: abap, alv

Currently I have an ALV grid and I can double click to call transaction `IE03` and pass the information in the first column (which is `eqkt-equnr`). However, this transaction is called  regardless of what column you click on. This wouldn't be so bad, but I need to be able to call `IW33` if you click on the 3rd column and pass along the `equz-J_3GEIGNER` value there.

My current double click code is as follows. `t_report` is my struct and `matnr` is the `equnr` part of it. `maktx` is the `J_3GEIGNER` part of it.

```
FORM user_command USING r_ucomm
     wa_selrow TYPE slis_selfield.

   IF r_ucomm = '&IC1'.
     READ TABLE t_report INDEX wa_selrow-tabindex.
     IF sy-subrc = 0.
       SET PARAMETER ID 'EQN' FIELD t_report-matnr.
       CALL TRANSACTION 'IE03' AND SKIP FIRST SCREEN.
     ENDIF.
   ENDIF.
ENDFORM.
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the field `wa_selrow-fieldname` to determine which column was clicked. Be aware that you may have to switch the grid from row selection mode to cell selection mode - since you didn't show us how you created the grid in the first place, I can't tell you how to do this in your case. Take a look at the [`SEL_MODE` property](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp2004/helpdata/en/ef/a2e9eff88311d2b48d006094192fe3/content.htm), it might help.

Comment: I am fairly sure it is cell selection mode (when running it will highlight individual cells). What do I check wa_selrow-fieldname against? I've tried 'Equipment’ ‘EQUNR’ t_report-matnr and eqkt-equnr

Comment: "Fairly sure" will get you nowhere - either it is or it isn't. As for the field name - have you considered using the debugger to inspect the contents of the parameters?

Comment: @vwegert, it still works on other columns even when I specify the field on which it is to be acted upon exclusively.   `IF RS_SELFIELD-FIELDNAME = 'EBELN'`.